# Speeding up encryption?

Tags: java, android, video, encryption, aes

I have this code for encrypting video files.

```
public static void encryptVideos(File fil,File outfile)
{ 
  try{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fil);
    //File outfile = new File(fil2);
    int read;
    if(!outfile.exists())
      outfile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
    FileInputStream encfis = new FileInputStream(outfile);
    Cipher encipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    //byte key[] = {0x00,0x32,0x22,0x11,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x23,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    //Lgo
    encipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, encipher);
    while((read = cis.read())!=-1)
      {
        fos.write(read);
        fos.flush();
      }   
    fos.close();
  }catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
  }
}
```

but the files which I am using are very big and using this method it takes too much time.
How can I speed this up?

Comment: Encyrption is resource intensive.  The whole idea is that you are mangling the content in a complicated way.

Comment: What speed *do* you get? Have you tried *mapping* the file and performing encryption on the ByteBuffer's returned (ps dunno if this is possible for android, overlooked tag)?

Comment: I am newbie I dont know that its possible

Comment: Well, [filechannel](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) seems to have been defined. Could you *please* post the speeds you are currently getting for encryption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this looks very slow to start with:

```
while((read = cis.read())!=-1)
{
    fos.write(read);
    fos.flush();
}
```

You're reading and writing a single byte at a time *and flushing the stream*. Do it a *buffer* at a time:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // Or whatever
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = cis.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
fos.flush(); // Not strictly necessary, but can avoid close() masking issues
```

Also note that you're *only* closing `fos` (not `cis` or `fis`), and you should be closing all of them in `finally` blocks.

Comment: My file is about 300mb this method made it more slower than earlier

Comment: @Navdroid: This is *slower* than reading and writing a single byte at a time? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: I am new at this sir ..I also find this confusing But the older method  was faster than your method...

Comment: @Navdroid: I suspect you may have messed up your diagnostics then. Also, you can try with different buffer sizes - you might want to try 64K, for example.

Comment: No I have checked my code but there is no other problem I tried increasing the size of buffer but nothing still same speed

Comment: @Navdroid: Is it possible that you were getting an exception (and swallowing it) before? An empty catch block like that is a *really bad idea*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8344/discussion-between-navdroid-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: Sir if u like to continue the discussion please click http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8344/discussion-between-navdroid-and-jon-skeet

Comment: @Navdroid: No, chat doesn't fit in well with my workflow I'm afraid. But you should definitely remove that empty catch block.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would not be surprised if the OS is already buffering the bytes, and an encrypt uses *way* more cycles per byte than the simple loop to get each byte.

Comment: @owlstead: But flushing the stream on each byte? There's still no reason I can think of that the buffer-at-a-time version should be slower than the per-byte-with-flush version.

Comment: If their stream implementations are not buffered, that flush is not going to do much. If the stream is already buffered, then of course the buffer handling is going to add code, and possibly memory management. Big differences would be pretty weird I admit.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the android NDK to write that part of your app with C++ to get significant performance boost. This looks like the kind of situation that would benefit from it. And there might already be something like this made with NDK.

Answer (score 0):

you should try Facebook Conceal. It's incredibly fast!

https://github.com/facebook/conceal